# 401 Authentication error for JIRA REST API with Basic Auth + Personal Access Token

Tags: jira-rest-api

Hello I am trying to connect to the JIRA Rest API to obtain the JSON Data for further parsing. I am using BASIC Auth + Personal Access Token Token (PAT) generated with my company login

I get an error 401 : Unauthorized. What I am doing wrong. I am new to .NET and would really help if experts in our community help fix the code or let me know what I am doing wrong. I am expecting JSON Data from the URL for a given component under a project. I am admin on that project and can see the JSON data when opening the URL directly in a browser.

With the WSSO redirection it gives the error NO redirection URL found.
Expecting to get back Json data but getting Authentication denied (401) Unauthorized error

[JIRA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGsDi.png)

Comment: You should include the code you've tried.  (are you trying to get this from front-end or back-end?) It sounds like you need to get/set some headers with your tokens.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore  The redirection error sounds like a bad request to the authorization server.

Comment: Hi pcalkins, I am trying to paste the code directly as is in the VS 2022 with proper formatting and spaces, but it does not allow saving anything saying indent the code

Comment: Can I share the code with you offline and see you can see what is going on? I am trying it 2 ways. Trying through REST API and also see possibility if this can be done by URL Content scrapping into JSON format and then parse it. Problem is the authentication.

Comment: I'm no expert in SSO or JIRA endpoints... It looks like you're trying a flow for SSO that would require you to do that through a browser.... you need to see if the JIRA endpoint allows or can have an app registered with it to use the API.  Right now it sounds like you are trying to emulate the calls of another server and you have the redirect URL wrong.  You should contact whoever is admin or support for the endpoint you are trying to access.  If that's not possible you could possibly automate the whole process using something like Selenium.

Comment: To explain further, this redirectURL is (I think) usually used for the authorization server to provide a proof of authorization to a resource provider/server (via browser redirection), which then would begin a session and provide a session token of some kind...